# Can an Iframe have XSS vulnerabilities?

Tags: jsp, iframe, jstl, xss, veracode

Normally, after I finish my coding, I always check for security vulnerabilities (mainly XSS) using [veracode](http://www.veracode.com/). Most of the times in my JSP, if I have a code like: `<%=bean.getValues()%>` it's flagged as XSS vulnerable. To resolve it, I mainly use JSTL tags like `<c:out>`.

Now consider this scenario, I have a JSP, which I am loading with an `<iframe>`. The same piece of code as shown above is there. Veracode does not know that this jsp is shown in `<iframe>` and hence will throw this piece of code as XSS vulnerable. But if such a piece of code is in an `<iframe>`, does it not make it almost difficult to crack it via cross-site scripting, as `<iframe>` is difficult to hack into?

I am just a little bit confused. Any help will be appreciated here.

Comment: Anything that can be loaded in an `iframe` can be loaded outside an `iframe` too. You always need to escape output even if your page is in a frame.

Comment: @DarkFalcon : So that means we need to use jstl tags like `c:out` in an `iframe` as well to avert `XSS`, is it ?

Comment: @DarkFalcon : You mentioned here that : 'Anything that can be loaded in an `iframe` can be loaded outside an iframe too. ' How is that done ? Any links for that ?

Comment: In your browser, View->Page Source. Find the `<iframe>` tag. Copy the value of the `src` property. Make it absolute by combining it with the current page's URL if needed. Paste it in your address bar.

Comment: @DarkFalcon : Extremely interesting . I will check it out .